# ssh shell freezes with incomplete output after running top or tmux a

Tags: shell, ssh, top

I'm sshing from my Mac into an Ubuntu Server 20.04 instance (using key-based authentication).
When I type any variety of commands, I get partial output, and then the shell becomes unresponsive to any commands.

For example, I `ssh` and then run `top -bn1`:

```
ssh user@99.123.45.678 -p 8105
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1077-raspi aarch64)
...
  System load:            0.24
  Usage of /:             17.3% of 29.04GB
  Memory usage:           58%
  Swap usage:             0%
  Temperature:            41.4 C
  Processes:              199
  Users logged in:        1
  => /mnt/ssd is using 90.3% of 109.48GB
...

$ top -bn1

top - 21:38:16 up 10 days,  4:20,  3 users,  load average: 0.22, 0.24, 0.29
Tasks: 198 total,   1 running, 197 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  1.3 us,  3.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 94.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :   7809.3 total,    183.6 free,   3835.5 used,   3790.1 buff/cache
MiB Swap:      0.0 total,      0.0 free,      0.0 used.   3660.0 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 279799 ubuntu    20   0   10696   3040   2668 R  11.8   0.0   0:00.04 top
     10 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   5.9   0.0   2:22.20 rcu_preempt
   6366 ubuntu    20   0 1835284 993728   9860 S   5.9  12.4   1516:24 my_python_app
 278766 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   5.9   0.0   0:02.50 kworker/0:2-events
      1 root      20   0  169560  10472   5744 S   0.0   0.1   0:37.96 systemd
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:01.52 kthreadd
      3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_gp
      4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_par_gp
```

and after this point there is no further output, and any command, including `ctrl+c` has no visible effect.
If I try just `top`, then the command doesn't return and just hangs on a new line.

I can close my Mac Terminal window and ssh again, and get a similar result.

I also have a `tmux` session running, and when I try `tmux a`, it results in a completely blank screen, and I can't exit except to close the Mac Terminal window.

`sudo fisk -l` behaves similarly to `top -bn1`, producing incomplete output and then becoming unresponsive.

I can run simple commands like `echo "test"` and it works as expected.

Why are `top`, `tmux`, and `fdisk` not working as expected, and how can I get them to work?

Comment: Are the two machines on the same network? If not, is there an overzealous firewall between them? It feels like an MTU issue to me

Comment: They actually are on the same wifi network, however I'm ssh'ing through the public IP address and port that's exposed through my router. Usually I'm not on the same network and experience the same issue too

Comment: With that description they're not on the same network. Your router can handle hairpin nat properly, though?

Comment: I'm not sure about hairpinning. But I tried connecting my Mac through my mobile phone's hotspot so that it's on a different network. And still getting the same problems with command output being truncated and freezing

Comment: Try [reducing the MTU](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8168068#:~:text=Open%20system%20preferences%20%2C%20click%20on,as%20standard%201500%20or%20custom%20.) to see if that solves the problem. Try by 100 at a time, several times. If this solves the problem I'll write you an answer with some suggestions on how to fix the issue properly, because fiddling with the MTU is at best a stop-gap fudge.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it didn't resolve the issue. I decreased the MTU for my Mac's Wi-Fi adapter down to 1280, which is the minimum allowed, and applied the settings, but I'm still having the same issues